# Во что распаковывается словарь Python

Tags: python

Всем привет!
Пусть имеем словарь:

```py
d1 = {'a':1,'b':2}
```

Имеется функция:

```py
def function(a,b):
    print(a)
```

Мы можем вызвать функцию, путем распаковки словаря d1:

```py
function(**d1)
```

Следовательно словарь d1, в качестве аргумента функции, распаковывается в конструкцию вида:

```py
a = 1, b = 2
```

С другой стороны можно определить новый словарь как:

```py
d2 = {**d1}, или
d2 = dict(a = 1, b = 2)
```

Но нельзя вот так:

```py
d2 = {a = 1, b = 2}
```

Так во что именно распаковываются словари? Все зависит от контекста?

Comment: В кортежи Tuple

Comment: При передаче в функцию через две звездочки словарь распаковывается в словарь именованных параметров (не в конструкцию вида `a = 1, b = 2`)

Comment: Можно ли сопоставить четкую синтаксическую конструкцию операции **  ?

Comment: @and_noob нет, это и есть чёткая синтаксическая конструкция, описанная в документации. См. мой ответ, там есть ссылка.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы верно предположили — всё зависит от контекста, давайте же рассмотрим это детальнее.

*<sub>Примечание: Я использую `Python 3.8` для испытаний</sub>*

---

### Создание словаря с помощью литералов

Рассмотрим для того, чтобы понять отличия в других ситуациях.

Это самый привычный способ, выглядит это так:

```py
x = {'a': 'Hello', 'b': 'World'}
```

В данном примере словарь будет создан вызовом команды [BUILD_CONST_KEY_MAP](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#opcode-BUILD_CONST_KEY_MAP), которая является специализированной версией [BUILD_MAP](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#opcode-BUILD_MAP). Описание самое обыкновенное, не будем заострять на этом внимание.

### Создание словаря с помощью распаковки в литералах

*Пример:*

```py
d = {**x, **y, **z}
```

Этот способ отличается от первого. Главное, что нужно понять — это не имеет никакого отношения к именованным аргументам. Это специализированный способ. `Python` вызовет команду [BUILD_MAP_UNPACK](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#opcode-BUILD_MAP_UNPACK), чтобы осуществить такое создание. Описание команды гласит:

> Берёт `count` словарей из стека, объединяет их в один словарь, и помещает результат в стек. Осуществляет распаковку словарей в словарь вида `{**x, **y, **z}`.
>
> *Новое в версии 3.5.*

*<sub>Примечание: Вольный перевод. Sorry for my English :)</sub>*

### Распаковка в конструктор класса

*Пример:*

```py
x = {'a': 'Hello', 'b': 'World'}
d = dict(**x)
```

`Python` создаст кортеж из словаря, используя команду [BUILD_TUPLE](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#opcode-BUILD_TUPLE), а затем вызовет [CALL_FUNCTION_EX](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#opcode-CALL_FUNCTION_EX), которая в свою очередь по необходимости может вызвать [BUILD_MAP_UNPACK_WITH_CALL](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#opcode-BUILD_MAP_UNPACK_WITH_CALL). Выдержка из описания последней команды гласит:

> Это похоже на [BUILD_MAP_UNPACK](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#opcode-BUILD_MAP_UNPACK), но используется для `f(**x, **y, **z)` синтаксиса вызова.

*<sub>Примечание: Вольный перевод. Sorry for my English :)</sub>*

### Распаковка словаря в именованные аргументы

*Пример:*

```py
def f(a, b):
    print(a)
x = {'a': 'Hello', 'b': 'World'}
f(**x)
```

Процесс абсолютно аналогичен варианту выше.

---

В итоге можно сказать, что синтаксис `**` в приведённых Вами примерах будет работать по-разному, и команды, которые он порождает, сильно отличаются.

Answer (score 4):

Есть несколько разных синтаксисов для создания словаря.

**Вариант 1: литерал**

Инициализация словаря через литерал, элементы описываются парами `ключ: значение` через запятую:

```
d1 = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

Здесь и ключ, и значение – нормальные объекты Питона, поэтому ключ-имя должно быть строкой к кавычках (ну или другим hashable объектом).

---

**Вариант 2: конструктор**

Можно создать словарь через конструктор (который можно считать обычной функцией), обращаясь к классу:

```
dict(a=1, b=2)
```

В неё мы передаём содержимое словаря через именованные аргументы. При этом, часть до знака `=` является особой лексемой (похоже на переменные) и переводится в строку уже внутри, при создании словаря, кавычки тут неуместны.

---

`function(**d1)` – это распаковка элементов словаря в именованные (keyword) аргументы функции. Это [встроенный функционал языка](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) для передачи позиционных и именованных аргументов извне. Например, выражение `func(**{'type':'Event'})` эквивалентно `func(type='Event')` – только словарь аргументов можно ещё где-то отдельно создавать, модифицировать, передавать, что бывает крайне полезно.

Поэтому, в конструктор словаря (как в обычную функцию) мы можем передать именованные аргументы из другого словаря, в итоге скопировав его содержимое:

```
d2 = dict(**d1)
```

---

**Вариант 3: comprehension**

Есть ещё [comprehension синтаксис](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/comprehensions-in-python/), который позволяет лаконично создавать одни итерируемые объекты из других, например:

```
t = (3, 14, 15)
d = {x: x**2 for x in t}

d1 = {'e': 2.7182, 'pi': 3.1415}
d2 = {d1[key]: key for key in d1}
```

Насчёт выражения `d3 = {**d1}` точно не скажу, возможно это тоже comprehension, возможно вариант литерала, а возможно отдельный синтаксис; но суть понятна, тот же `dict(**d1)`.

---

Выражение `{a = 1, b = 2}` неправильно потому, что ему не соответствует никакой корректной синтаксической конструкции. `field=...` можно писать лишь в вызове функций, а внутри фигурных скобок ожидается только что-то из вариантов выше.

Поначалу это всё может немного путать, но не переживайте, так у всех, просто используйте те способы, которые подходят под конкретную задачу. C опытом в голове всё уляжется, а навыки выстроятся в цельную картинку `;)`

Comment: Насчёт первого. Вы имели в виду "с помощью литералов"?

Comment: @nomnoms12 блин, точно! Вечно забываю это слово  Спасибо 

Comment: интегрируемые - ? предположу, что итерируемые

Comment: @splash58 спасибо! Автозамена плохо шарит в ИТ терминах)

Comment: `d3 = {**d1}` — это в какой-то степени отдельный синтаксис.